# Web scraping Tennis24 in play stats

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, screen-scraping, webdriverwait

I have been trying to work out how to scrape the live and updating statistics on Tennis 24 "https://www.tennis24.com/match/4xFaW6fP/#match-statistics;0" a page such as this but when I try to use selenium nothing is returned. even if I just try to return the 1 element such as

```
<div class="statText statText--awayValue">4</div>
```

Could someone please give me some pointers as this is my first scraping project?

Comment: I would be easier if you add your code to the post in text mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the text **4** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.tennis24.com/match/4xFaW6fP/#match-statistics;0')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='statText statText--titleValue' and text()='Aces']//following::div"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute('innerHTML')`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.tennis24.com/match/4xFaW6fP/#match-statistics;0')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='statText statText--titleValue' and text()='Aces']//following::div"))).get_attribute('innerHTML'))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your speedy reply, I will have a go at that today and let you know how it goes.

Comment: thats brilliant thanks, really appreciated so how would I get all values in that table is it a case of getting all elements?

Comment: @BlindBlake That sounds to be a different requirement all together. Can you raise a new question with your new requirement please?

Comment: I have tried getting the numbers for player A by changing the "following::div" to Before::div) but its not working. am I completely off the mark here?

Comment: @BlindBlake Feel free to visit [Selenium Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) and help other users.